# Xubuntu Live USB suddenly asking for username and log in password but I did not set any

Tags: xubuntu, login, password

[Xubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB | Persistent | Created using UNetbootin]

**Things I've tried:**

1. Blank username and password
2. Username: ubuntu Password: blank
3. Username: xubuntu Password: blank
4. Username: xubuntu Password: xubuntu

Any solution to this?

Comment: try password "xubuntu"  (username should be 'xubuntu' unless you've changed it)

Comment: Tried that. No go.